# I am using Google Map in Reactjs without using any library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

**Map: Expected mapDiv of type Element but was passed null.**
Every time i am facing this issue how it can be sorted out if you have sorted this issue kindly help me[image]

Answer (score 1):

Call initMap() function after "map" element is added in DOM(In componentDidMount) . If you console.log the document.getElementById("map") before line number 24, you will be getting null.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue i faced is due to id parameter. If you use javascript method document.getElementById() same id must be pass with reference in container div. I appreciate for your answer.